# remove audio from mp4 file ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

I am on a Mac using Python 3.6. I am trying to remove audio from an mp4 file using ffmpeg but unfortunately it does not give me the "silenced" mp4 file I look for. Code I use is:

```
ffmpeg_extract_audio("input_file.mp4", "output_file.mp4", bitrate=3000, fps=44100)
```

It gives me a new output file with a low-quality video image, but still the audio. Any suggestion?

Comment: That function is the opposite of what you want to do (recognizable in it's params). Why not sticking to plain ffmpeg-usage (no moviepy)? Then it's a [one-liner](https://superuser.com/questions/268985/remove-audio-from-video-file-with-ffmpeg) (and easy to control untouched video-stream).

Comment: I finally got it with the ffmpeg plain usage, but now I have problems in looping over 245 movie files I have in a directory. The code that worked for a file is: `ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -c copy -an output_file.mp4`

Comment: Then either write a bash-script or use a python-script using os/glob/subprocess. I'm not sure if ffmpeg has a builtin wildcard-like feature for that.

Comment: ok thank you @sascha, I finally made it through: ´for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy -an "noaudio_$file"; done´

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/268985/remove-audio-from-video-file-with-ffmpeg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok thank you @sascha. I finally put all my mp4 files in the same folder and run the following code:

```
for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy -an "noaudio_$file"; done
```

If, like me, one uses Sublime Text or any other text editor (already using Python language), it run with the following:

```
import subprocess
command = 'for file in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy -an "noaudio_$file"; done'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

Comment: Add `-movflags +faststart` output option if the video is to be viewed via progressive download.

Comment: @martins, I tried your method. It returns nothing. Could you please tell if I need to add some path or do something. In my folder, I have some files other than mp4 as well. Could that be a reason ? I am trying it with Spyder and Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to accomplish the same thing but I couldn't install ffmpeg and moviepy was superslow

```
pip install opencv-python
```

```
import cv2

def remove_audio_with_opencv(input_file, output_file):
    # Create a VideoCapture object
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_file)

    # Check if the video opened successfully
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Error: Could not open video.")
        return

    # Get video properties
    frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

    # Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(output_file, fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))

    # Read until video is completed
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            # Write the frame to the output file
            out.write(frame)
        else:
            break

    # Release everything
    cap.release()
    out.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Usage
    input_video = "source_video_path.mp4"
    output_video = "path_video_noaudio.mp4"
    remove_audio_with_opencv(input_video, output_video)
```